# How does POS protocol handle the case where Staking node is offline

Tags: proof-of-stake, consensus, staking

How does POS protocol handle the case where Staking node is offline and was chosen by consensus algorithm as the next block creator. Will the task be delegated to some other node?

Let's say the node was online and got picked as a new node forger but then it went offline and may be will never be available again.

And when I would think one step further. How would validators of such a block know whether it is legitimate block if it would not be produced by the node that was chosen by consensus algorithm?